# How to make my help button will show matlab help?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-guide

Hye guyz.. If i want to make a help button for my figure. How can i make if the user pressed the help button, it will appear matlab helper which is like product help, function browser and etc.. How can i link it? Is there any tutorials regarding making a help button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Callback` property of the button to `'doc(''plot'')'`. This command will be executed when the button is pressed.

You can set the callback with the property editor in GUIDE. If you want to do it programmatically, you can generate the help button like this:

```
fh = figure
uicontrol('style','pushbutton','string','help','callback','doc(''plot'')','parent',fh)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following article [relevant.](http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/context-sensitive-help/)

Unfortunately, it appears that after many years of service, MathWorks has decided to finally remove this feature. I find this most regrettable because it is a fantastic feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`. For example,

- `eval('help plot')` will show help on the `help` command in the command window.
- `eval('doc plot')` will open a document help file for the `plot` command.