# Creating help button

Tags: matlab, codeigniter, uitableview, user-interface, matlab-guide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make my help button will show matlab help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224533/how-to-make-my-help-button-will-show-matlab-help)

Hye guys.. I need help here. How can i make a help pushbuttons for my figure.  For example, when i push help button, then it will popup the menu list(which is the help of my program)? What i mean is, i have a program that i created using GUIDE and then if you are the user of my program, for sure you need help with it. So how can i make my program as a user-friendly program? I plan to create a help button so that user can understand my coding.. How to popup the help??

Comment: can you please provide more information about the code where you want to put the help button in, etc'? this will help you get more answers - and better ones

Comment: i think you need jquery - not codeigniter, for this. you are talking about a front-end enhancement, not a server behavior.

Comment: @raymond: if this is a MATLAB question, why is it tagged "codeigniter"?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to create popups using codeigniter , have a look at this
[URL HELPER](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
$atts = array(
              'width'      => '800',
              'height'     => '400',
              'scrollbars' => 'yes',
              'status'     => 'yes',
              'resizable'  => 'yes',
              'screenx'    => '0',
              'screeny'    => '0'
            );

echo anchor_popup('news/local/123', 'Click Me!', $atts);
```